# Will a processor with such a defect work?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-usage, motherboard

I bought a processor, but it arrived with such a defect. I want to know from you, will it even work?[image]
I haven’t tested the processor itself, since the warranty will be void, but I’m still interested in whether it will work or is it a matter of luck? It’s just that even if it starts, won’t it burn out after some time?

Comment: Please read about acceptable questions in the [help/on-topic]. This isn't a programming question.

Comment: It was probably dropped at some point. It looks like the substrate has some damage, but it may still work. It could be risky putting it in a good system though as there's a chance a CPU failure might cause other failures. If it was sold to you as working without mention of this flaw, I think you have good grounds to return it for a refund or replacement. If you bought on Ebay, they can be quite favourable towards buyers in situations like this.